# How To Get HTML Formatted Stored Text To Display Properly

Tags: html, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE as a RTE. The data is storing properly in my database. However when I go to retrieve the data it is not being displayed with the formats, even though the format is there.
I added a hard coded line of the formatted text, copied from the database, to verify that it is being stored properly. The issueStatus contains the same text as what is hard coded (as you can see in the screen shot).

The code

```
@Model.IssueData.issueStatus<br />
<p>This text is<strong> BOLD</strong></p>
```

Here is how it is displaying.

[image: Here is How it is displaying]

What do I need to do to get the stored text to display properly?

Comment: @Html.Raw(Model.IssueData.issueStatus)

Comment: @MikeBrind - Thanks this was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

@MikeBrind had the solution. I needed to use @HtmlRaw.